# Rainbows at other wavelengths

Tags: refraction

I'm curious as to whether or not it is possible to have a rainbow at wavelengths other than visible light. I'm familiar with Snell's refraction law and why it is that they occur, but now what about other wavelengths, such as radio, microwaves, or IR, let alone much shorter wavelengths, like in the Ultraviolet or X-Rays.

Thank you for your time,

Comment: How would you detect it?

Comment: @KyleKanos I don't know...using a camera that is sensitive to those wavelengths? I know there are CCDs capable of operating reasonably well (after all, look at what they're taking up on JWST). Perhaps if we looked out into the Universe we might see them weakly in nebulae or supernova remnants?

Comment: Yes, there is dispersion at wavelengths other than the optical, so there are "rainbows". They should be rather easy to produce in the lab, but I doubt that astronomical objects will produce detectable rainbows, they are simply not dense enough and most (expect gas clouds that are close to the solar system) have too small an angular diameter to produce a full rainbow equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fascinating question. But if you mean rainbows in other wavelengths **from the Sun**, yes to UV and IR, but no to Xrays. Simply because there's no significant radiation from the Sun at Xray wavelengths (see [this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzeSJ.gif) for radiation per wavelength).

Most of the Sun's radiation is at visible wavelengths, which I guess is no coincidence. Life on Earth has evolved to use the light available!

There are definately detectable rainbows at other wavelengths tho. See [here](http://www.grad.ucl.ac.uk/comp/2007-2008/research/gallery/index.pht?entryID=183) for pics in UV (slightly inside the visible rainbow) and IR (slightly outside).

Comment: The 2nd hyperlink (the photo) is broken.  Here is the archived version:  https://web.archive.org/web/20110718165204/http://www.grad.ucl.ac.uk/comp/2007-2008/research/gallery/index.pht?entryID=183

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It is possible to produce rainbows of Ultraviolet or X-Rays in the lab. The [SLAC](http://www6.slac.stanford.edu/news/2014-12-03-slac-radiabeam-build-new-tool-tweak-rainbows-x-ray-laser-light.aspx) team has already built a tool to produce rainbows of X-ray.