Can the rainbow illustrate the colors we can’t see?
Seen as how we’re only able to see a relatively small portion of the electromagnetic spectrum, does the rainbow “keep going” in the frequencies we cannot see?
In other words; if we were able to see all EM radiation from infrared to gamma rays, would we see the rainbow as a continuous surface rather than one or two bows?

https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/185231/174766

If you are asking specifically about rainbows in the sky, then the answer will depend on; (1) Which wavelengths are emitted by the Sun's photosphere, (2) Which wavelengths are able to penetrate Earths' atmosphere, (3) Which wavelengths are able to pass through liquid water, and (4) Which wavelengths are small enough that they don't just pass by a tiny water droplet without interacting. Photons more energetic than mid-range UV never reach the ground. Microwaves and radio waves have wavelengths much longer than the size of an airborne water droplet.
